# Is there a Flex component that clips any graphics being drawn outside its bounds?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'm using the `graphics` class to object to draw on BorderContainer. Some of the drawings fall off the components borders, but they are still drawn on screen. Is there any way to clip the area drawn with graphics?

What's the recommend component to draw on, anyway? I need the simplest thing that can I can draw on in Flex and have the ability to add Labels to as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On restricting drawing to a given region, try using the [mask](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mask) property (every subclass of `DisplayObject` has it).  It was created to do exactly what you're asking about.

On the simplest *IVisualElementContainer* you can draw on, try using a [Group](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Group.html).

Comment: Thanks, mask worked. Added it in the Declarations area and drawn a black rect for the area that needs to be drawn upon.

Answer (score 4):

If you're skinning the BorderContainer, just set clipAndEnableScrolling to true on the Skin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
        clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.BorderContainer")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <!-- states -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="disabled" />
        <s:State name="normal" />
    </s:states>

    <!-- SkinParts
    name=contentGroup, type=spark.components.Group, required=false
    -->
</s:Skin>
```

As mentioned, Group or SpriteVisualElement are lean to draw on.  Also, a mask would be good if needed.

Do you need Spark Labels or just TextFields?

Maybe creating a spark.components.SkinnableContainer you can apply skin classes would be ideal?

**Implementation** - Skinnable Container sets the skin you draw on, and you place your MXML content inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955"
               minHeight="600"
               xmlns:local="*">

    <!-- do you drawing in the skin -->
    <local:ExampleContainer skinClass="ExampleSkin">

        <!-- apply content as needed -->
        <s:Label text="My Text" />

        <!-- etc... each instance custom content -->

    </local:ExampleContainer>

</s:Application>
```

**Example Container**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SkinnableContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                      width="400"
                      height="300"
                      skinClass="ExampleSkin">


</s:SkinnableContainer>
```

**Example Skin** - Do your drawing here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<!--- The default skin class for a Spark SkinnableContainer container.  

     @see spark.components.SkinnableContainer

      @langversion 3.0
      @playerversion Flash 10
      @playerversion AIR 1.5
      @productversion Flex 4
-->
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" alpha.disabled="0.5">

    <fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[ 
        /** 
         * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
         */
        [HostComponent("spark.components.SkinnableContainer")]
    ]]>
    </fx:Metadata> 

    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
        <![CDATA[         
            /**
             *  @private
             */
            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number) : void
            {
                // Push backgroundColor and backgroundAlpha directly.
                // Handle undefined backgroundColor by hiding the background object.
                if (isNaN(getStyle("backgroundColor")))
                {
                    background.visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    background.visible = true;
                    bgFill.color = getStyle("backgroundColor");
                    bgFill.alpha = getStyle("backgroundAlpha");
                }

                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            }
        ]]>        
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
    </s:states>

    <!--- Defines the appearance of the SkinnableContainer class's background. -->
    <s:Rect id="background" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:fill>
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:SolidColor id="bgFill" color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!--
        Note: setting the minimum size to 0 here so that changes to the host component's
        size will not be thwarted by this skin part's minimum size.   This is a compromise,
        more about it here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-21143
    -->
    <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableContainer#contentGroup -->
    <s:Group id="contentGroup" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
        <s:layout>
            <s:BasicLayout/>
        </s:layout>
    </s:Group>

</s:Skin>
```

Comment: weirdly, this causes the rectangles not to be shown at all. if I set clipAndEnableScrolling to false it works...

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use **SpriteVisualElement** to draw to, set it's width and height to 100% and put it in a **Group**. Then enable the Group's property **clipAndEnableScrolling** and you're all good. You can also add Labels as elements to the group :]

Here is an example with code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           creationComplete="onCreationComplete(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Label;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.core.SpriteVisualElement;

        protected function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            var spriteVisualElement:SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement();

            spriteVisualElement.percentWidth = 100;
            spriteVisualElement.percentHeight = 100;

            spriteVisualElement.graphics.beginFill(0xFFAABB);
            spriteVisualElement.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
            spriteVisualElement.graphics.endFill();

            myContainer.addElement(spriteVisualElement);

            var helloWorldLabel:Label = new Label();
            helloWorldLabel.text = "Hello world!";
            myContainer.addElement(helloWorldLabel);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Group id="myContainer"
         width="100"
         height="100"
         horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" 
         clipAndEnableScrolling="true"/>

</s:Application>
```

Hope this helps,

Blaze

P.S. The most simple thing you can draw on (as far as I know) is the **Sprite** class but Sprite is not **IVisualElement**.

From the Flex documentation:

*The **SpriteVisualElement** class is a light-weight Sprite-based **implemention of the IVisualElement** interface. **Spark containers can lay out and render SpriteVisualElement** objects.*

Another solution would be to try and draw the things you want to with the spark primitives (s:Rect, s:Line, s:Path, s:Ellipse, etc.)